# is an expired ssl certificate validated similar to an invalid certificate in SSL pinning?

Tags: ssl, https, ssl-certificate, tls1.2

I have root , intermediate and leaf certificate.

If I pin all these certificates in my mobile application , then let's say `leaf` cert has expired.

But the connection will be still accepted since intermediate and root certs are pinned already.

What if someone sends a different certificate that is not my expired leaf certificate but it is signed by the same intermediate or root certificate ?

Does the connection still be established since the root and intermediate certs are same in this different certificate also ?

Answer (score 0):

There are various types of pinning in use:

- One can pin against a leaf certificate. This means only this certificate will be accepted. This can also be optionally combined with additionally checking for expiration, revocation etc in which case the certificate will only be accepted if it is the expected one and it also fits the additional constraints (expiration, ...).
- One can pin against the public key of the leaf certificate. This is like pinning against the leaf certificate itself but it will also handle certificate renewal as long as the public key stays the same. Again, this can be optionally combined with checking for expiration etc.
- One can pin against a specific CA certificate. In this case normal certificate validation will be done (i.e. building trust path, checking subject, expiration, ...) but additionally it will be required that a specific CA or a certificate with the same public key is part of the trust chain, either as intermediate certificate or root certificate.

> If I pin all these certificates in my mobile application , then let's say leaf cert has expired.
>   But the connection will be still accepted since intermediate and root certs are pinned already.

If pinning against a leaf certificate was done then it will only accept the expired certificate if no additional constrains (specifically check expiration) are part of the pinning.

> What if someone sends a different certificate that is not my expired leaf certificate but it is signed by the same intermediate or root certificate ?

If pinning against a specific leaf certificate was done it will not accept any other certificate as leaf certificate, no matter if also pinning against CA certificates was done. The idea is that all requirements are satisfied and not only some.

If instead only pinning to CA certificates was done then normal certificate validation will be done (specifically that subject matches the expected domain) and additionally it will be checked that the pinned CA are in the trust path.

Comment: "it will not accept any other certificate as leaf certificate, no matter if also pinning against CA certificates was done" . This is wrong. I tested giving an invalid leaf cert but the same root cert and connection got accepted.

Comment: @Nateshbhat: *"I tested ...."* - as you can see I described various ways pinning can be implemented - there is no single way encompassing all TLS stack, OS, applications etc. I have no idea how you've implemented it and in which environment. But given what you get as results of your tests it looks like you've implemented it in an insecure way since obviously it should not behave like that.

Answer (score -1):

I tested pinning SSL certificates (certificate in the form of a pem file) inside a dart application using the `setTrustedCertificates` method of the ClientChannel.

#### Observations :

**Connection is established successfully when :**

- When valid root cert , valid intermediate cert and NUCLEI’s NON EXPIRED leaf cert is pinned.
- When valid root cert ,valid intermediate cert and NUCLEI’s EXPIRED leaf cert is pinned.
- When valid root cert ,valid intermediate cert and INVALID leaf cert is pinned.
- When only the VALID NUCLEI’s leaf cert is pinned.
- When one NON EXPIRED Nuclei’s leaf cert and one EXPIRED Nuclei’s leaf cert are pinned.

**Connection fails with CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED error when :**

- When just INVALID leaf cert is pinned.
- When EXPIRED leaf cert is pinned.

#### Conclusions :

- There is no point in pinning all the root , intermediate and leaf certs of a single host.
- Any invalid malicious leaf cert but signed by the same root or intermediate cert is also accepted.
- So it is better to just pin the leaf cert. But if concern is regarding the leaf certificate expiring , then we have to go with pinning the intermediate cert and just remove the leaf cert from the pin.
- **For Maximum Security**

  - we should pin only the leaf cert.
  - To cope up with certificate expiry , we can pin multiple leaf certs with different expiry times.
  - If pinning multiple leaf certs is not an option , then the best option is to just pin the intermediate cert and remove all other certs from the pinning.

Comment: *"I did some testing ..."* - on what platform, which application, which TLS stack, which specific implementation of pinning? There is no single way. And for me it looks like your implementations where wrong and insecure since you did not implement pinning as **ALL** these conditions have to be met but instead as **ANY** of these conditions have to be met.

Comment: I don't think that setTrustedCertificates is the correct way to implement pinning in the first place. It is not about pinning but about setting the possible trust anchors for verification. This means it will trust a certificate if  **any** of the given certificates is in the trust path, no matter if leaf or CA certificate. In other words: it is not that pinning behaves as you describe but that you don't properly implement pinning.